# node.js lost update writing JSON file

Tags: node.js

I got a Problem with fs; in the SQL universe you would call it lost update.

**Background Story:**
I got a tiny application, that should store some data provided by the user to a JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "givenname": "Joe",
    "surname": "Doe",
    "dob": "1990-04-01"
  },
  {
    "givenname": "Tim",
    "surname": "Cake",
    "dob": "2000-01-01"
  }
]
```

And I got some JS to update the file:

```
// sync
var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(data_path, 'utf8'));
data.push(user);
var str = JSON.stringify(data);
setTimeout(function () {
    fs.writeFileSync(data_path, str);
    res.send({'status': 'success'});
}, 5000);

// same story but async
fs.readFile(data_path, 'utf8', function (err, _data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var data = JSON.parse(_data);
    data.push(user);
    setTimeout(function () {
        fs.writeFile(data_path, JSON.stringify(data), function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.send({'status': 'error'})
            }
            res.send({'status': 'success'})
        })
    }, 5000);
});
```

I inserted the `SetTimeout(..., 5000)` to have some more time to test the application.

No matter if I do it sync or async, If I post some data to the app, for example `{"givenname": "g01", "surname": "s01", "dob": "2016-01-01"}` and post some other data within the 5 seconds, for example `{"givenname": "g02", "surname": "s02", "dob": "2016-02-02"}`, the first record (g01, s01) will be lost.
I know that in production the timespan between reading and writing the file will be much shorter, but obviously it does exist and it can corrupt the data.

**So my question is:**
Is there a possibility to avoid that loss of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is the file is being read by execution `A` which then sleeps for 5 seconds. Meanwhile, execution `B` reads the file and waits for 5 seconds. Then `A` writes it's output, then `B` writes it's output *overwriting* the previous output from `A`.

For a single process accessing the file, the synchronous version you have *without* the sleep will work:

```
var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(data_path, 'utf8'));
data.push(user);
var str = JSON.stringify(data);
fs.writeFileSync(data_path, str);
res.send({'status': 'success'});
```

It's not particularly scalable (locking up your process for a read and a write), but it will work.

Comment: I know whats happening, but I didn't know that sync will work flawlessly. Thx.